# not converting ÷ to � in some system with internet browsert

Tags: javascript, unicode, flash, utf8-decode

we are using flash file to create questions and user input is  pass into our asp .net web page  by calling external javascript method.

example user has entered the input string as "7 × 8 ÷ 9"  and click on flash file submit button the external javascript method  is called and string is passed in to  webpage is as same as entered in flash file "7 × 8 ÷ 9". in most of all system with all browser works fine, but one particular system  in IE browser   returning string as "7 Ã— 8 Ã• 9" (Unicode UTF 8 format) other browsers are working fine in this system .

Operating System:  Windows 8    (The same OS installed in other system also works fine)
Internet Explorer: IE 10 (version 10.0.9200.16618) the some IE version work in other system

Please suggest any specific system configuration required to work Unicode UTF 8 format or required any Unicode font's to install for the system

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the JavaScript code doing? If there is a form submission, what encoding is the page served as? What is the server side written in and what is doing with the submission?

Answer (score 0):

The string “7 Ã— 8 Ã• 9” is what you get when you have “7 × 8 ÷ 9” in UTF-8 encoding and the data gets misinterpreted as windows-1252 encoded. So this is a character encoding issue; check out the W3C page [Character encodings](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset). Without additional information, it is impossible to tell what specifically goes wrong in this case.